# SQL query: Get number of days for each state

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that containes a list of movements:

```
+----+----------+------------+------------+
| id | boat_id  | date       | state      |
+----+----------+------------+------------+
|  1 |        2 | 2020-01-03 |          1 |
|  2 |        2 | 2020-01-23 |          3 |
|  3 |        2 | 2020-03-02 |          1 |
|  4 |        2 | 2020-03-29 |          2 |
+----+----------+------------+------------+
```

I need a SQL query to get the number of days the boat is in each state, with a date range given.

For example, with range 2020-03-01 - 2020-03-31:
The latest movement change was: state 3 date '2020-01-23'. So 2020-03-01 state is 3 until 2020-03-02, that it changes to 1. Then state remains at 1 until 2020-03-29 that changes to 2.

The result would be:
State 3 days: 1 (from 2020-03-01 to 2020-03-02)
State 1 days: 27 (from 2020-03-02 to 2020-03-29)
State 2 days: 3 (from 2020-03-29 to 2020-03-31)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? You're much more likely to get an answer if you can illustrate some effort on your end in attempting to solve the problem before posting it here.

Comment: you can use the LEAD()-function to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . this is a bit of a pain.  After all, you might have no dates with in *at all*.

But you can handle this with `lead()`:

```
select t.boat_id, t.state,
       sum( datediff(least(coalesce(next_date, '2020-04-01'), '2020-04-01'),
                     greatest(date, '2020-03-01')
                    )
          ) as days_in_march_2020
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by boat_id order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where date < '2020-04-01' and
      (next_date is null or next_date >= '2020-03-01')
group by t.boat_id, t.state
```